# What i have use to replace flask_pewee get_fields

Tags: python, flask, centos6, flask-admin, flask-peewee

Issue come after flask_pewee update

I have following line in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_peewee/filters.py

```
 for field_obj in model._meta.get_fields():
```

And error is:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_peewee/filters.py", line 210, in make_field_tree
    for field_obj in model._meta.get_fields():
AttributeError: 'ModelOptions' object has no attribute 'get_fields'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one can be fixed by update flask_peewee package with latest master from github

At current moment it not work via pip